# stash REST API: how do you specify the 2nd commit ID in a diff?

Tags: rest, bitbucket-server

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.10.2/stash-rest.html#idp2008384

> /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/commits/{commitId}/diff/{path:.*}

Where does the 2nd commit ID go? There's supposed to be a source and destination ID but it's unclear how to format this, and there are no example queries.

Comment: Maybe you can use the api "/REST/API/1.0/PROJECTS/{PROJECTKEY}/REPOS/{REPOSITORYSLUG}/COMMITS?" first to get the commits ,there are commitids in.
And I don't know how to request the url by authentication,you can tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

oh -- never mind, it's the `since` query parameter. I saw two `commitId` parameters in the table and it confused me.